# Number of solutions in a field of order $32$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field of order $32$. Then find the number of non-zero solutions $(a,b)\in F\times F$ of the equation $x^2+xy+y^2=0$.

As , $|F|=32$ , so $(F\setminus\{0\},.)$ forms a group of order $31$, which is prime. So , $F\setminus \{0\}\simeq\mathbb Z_{31}$.

Then how I proceed ?

Comment: Hint: $31$ times the number of solutions of $t^2+t+1=0$.

Comment: How the solutions of $t^2+t+1=0$ ?

Comment: I don't know what tools you have. Maybe the following will be useful, depending on what you know. Is the $4$-element field a subfield of the $32$-element field?  Or does $x^4-x$ divide $x^{32}-x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x^2 + xy + y^2=0$, then $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0$.

But $3$ does not divide $31$, so $a\mapsto a^3$ is injective, and therefore $x=y$.

Comment: $x=y$ .It is clear..But then? I am unable to understand..Please elaborate.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 If $x=y$, then $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3x^2=0$.

Comment: @slade how can we deduce $x=y$ just from the fact that 3 doesn't divide 31.

Comment: @lbs We don't conclude it directly.  First, we use the fact that $(3,31)=1$ to conclude that $a\mapsto a^3$ is injective.  Then, we use the fact that $x^3=y^3$ to conclude that $x=y$.  Which step is confusing?

Comment: @lbs Assuming it's the first step: It's enough to show that $a\mapsto a^3$ is injective on $F^\times$.  But, as indicated in the question, this is a cyclic group of order $31$, so this is equivalent to saying that $3$ is a primitive root modulo $31$, which holds because $(3,31)=1$.